# Multiple Datastax Agents on one IP

Tags: datastax, agents, opscenter

I'm trying to setup datastax agents on separate server to monitor nodes. But I've faced with problem. How to configure multiple agents on one IP address? In agent config I can define only agent_rpc_interface, but can't do this for port. So in this case if I need to monitor 4 nodes, I need 4 interfaces on this server, but I have only one interface. 
Is there any workarounds on this?
-=-=-=-
Still cant find solution for this.
Also, how to get metrics from node? In logs I have

```
INFO [install-location-finder] 2014-02-20 16:02:42,380 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
INFO [install-location-finder] 2014-02-20 16:02:42,388 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
INFO [install-location-finder] 2014-02-20 16:02:42,401 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
```

But agent installed on another host, so how to override this address?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataStax Agent is designed to run on the actual Cassandra nodes and monitor with a 1:1 ratio. Hence, there is no way to specify multiple IP addresses.

A typical cluster setup would have:

- 1 OpsCenter node
- N Cassandra nodes, each running Cassandra + DataStax Agent

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux, you will be able to create a network alias and assign more than one ip addresses to same NIC. For more info check this out http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-creating-or-adding-new-network-alias-to-a-network-card-nic/